# Understanding why ArcSDE FeatureLayer is read only and FeatureTypes property is null?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, wpf

I have a WPF FeatureLayer backed by an ArcSDE 10 feature class that I hope to use for editing. After the layer is done initializing its readOnly property is true, I think that this points to some problem with the ArcSDE setup but I can't figure out what it could be.

I've verified that the connection is working, inspecting the FeatureLayer shows that it has downloaded the remote table name. The post installation setup for ArcSDE had no trouble, same with creating some empty feature classes, adding them to an mxd file and using it to host a feature service. Is there any other setup I may have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature services and map services have different URLs to access them on the server, and I was using a map service URL from an earlier version of the project to initialize my feature layer. Oops.

```
http://mysite.mydomain.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/mymap/MapServer/0
http://mysite.mydomain.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/mymap/FeatureServer/0
```

It was ESRI's [interactive SDK](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#ToolkitEditorWidget) examples for feature layer editing that clued me in (though it took a few looks to notice the tiny change in the URL!).

The various services and URls are [documented on ESRI's site](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/) too.